# How to force < iframe> to be sticky in on side on the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make  with google maps reference stick on the right side of my page I've tried this code still scrolls with the rest of the page

```css
#map{
position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="map" id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d317715.71193692513!2d-0.38178583985785625!3d51.528735196048615!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75%3A0x52963a5addd52a99!2sLondon%2C%20UK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sae!4v1589590348452!5m2!1sen!2sae" width="600" height="700" frameborder="0" style="border:0; width: 100%;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: add `right: 0;` or `left: 100%;` maybe

Answer (score 0):

This should stick your map to the top *(I've added a `div` to be able to scroll down)*:

```css
#map {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="map" id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d317715.71193692513!2d-0.38178583985785625!3d51.528735196048615!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75%3A0x52963a5addd52a99!2sLondon%2C%20UK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sae!4v1589590348452!5m2!1sen!2sae" width="600" height="700" frameborder="0" style="border:0; width: 100%;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>

<div>Extra Space</div>
```

If you want to the right, `right: amount` should do the trick. `left` for left and `bottom` for bottom.

@Edit - I've found that setting `right` does not seem to be working. I've searched around and seems like there are several rules when it comes for something to be sticky. I haven't used sticky yet so I don't know if I'm just missing something. I apologize as my comment is most likely useless in your case.

You might want to check [Interneting Is Hard](https://www.internetingishard.com/html-and-css/advanced-positioning/) if you want to learn more about positioning, though it does not have sticky, it should have enough for your needs without the use of sticky.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

```css
#map {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="map" id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d317715.71193692513!2d-0.38178583985785625!3d51.528735196048615!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75%3A0x52963a5addd52a99!2sLondon%2C%20UK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sae!4v1589590348452!5m2!1sen!2sae" width="600" height="700" frameborder="0" style="border:0; width: 100%;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

Elements with `position:fixed` will stay in place when their parent element is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

add 
**`top:0;`** 
in #map. this will stick the page at the top. This way you can user css position.

Answer (score 0):

Make a sticky div before you insert your iframe in.

```
<div style="position:sticky; top:3vh;">
  <iframe src="page.html"></iframe>
</div>
```